# How to set new locale state from observable array in React?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

I have an initial array: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and want to add 1 to each item in array.

The code looks as following:

```
import React from 'react';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            fromArray: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const observable$ = from(this.state.fromArray).pipe(
            map(value => ({
                observable: value + 1
            }))
        );

        this._subscription = observable$.subscribe(
            result => this.setState({...result})
        )
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    render() {
        const { fromArray } = this.state;

        return (
            <ul>
                {
                    fromArray.map((item, index) => <li key={index}>{item}</li>)
                }
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

But, I've got the initial array in the list only.

How to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/r03jloo3xn) is the demo. There are 2 problems here:

- in `map` function you get an updated element of array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6). But you need to have the new array itself to be set in the state. That's why I've used `reduce`.
- you need to specify which part of the state you are setting. Not in this way: `result => this.setState({...result})`, but in this: `newFromArray => this.setState({ fromArray: newFromArray })`

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { from } from "rxjs";
import { reduce } from "rxjs/operators";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      fromArray: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const observable$ = from(this.state.fromArray).pipe(
      reduce((acc, value) => [...acc, value + 1], [])
    );

    this._subscription = observable$.subscribe(newFromArray => {
      return this.setState({ fromArray: newFromArray });
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  render() {
    const { fromArray } = this.state;

    return (
      <ul>
        {fromArray.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any other way to achieve it by using some another method, not reduce?

Comment: @tesicg you can replace `reduce((acc, value) => [...acc, value + 1], [])` with `map(value => value + 1),toArray()`

Comment: It's prefect. Thank you very much.